# Error after executing a cursor (oracle 11g - divisor is equal to zero)

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

After executing my cursor i got this error message: **divisor is equal to zero**

```
SELECT   oel.org_id,
         oeh.header_id,
         oel.line_id,
         oeh.order_number,
     sum(mr.reservation_quantity) quantity,
     oel.order_quantity_uom uom_code,
     oel.unit_selling_price,
     (oel.tax_value/oel.ordered_quantity) unit_tax_value,
     (nvl(sum(mr.reservation_quantity),0) - oel.ordered_quantity)
  FROM   oe_order_lines_all oel
  , oe_order_headers_all oeh
  , oe_order_sources oos
  , ra_terms_b  rt
  , ra_terms_b_dfv rt_dfv
  , mtl_reservations mr
  , mtl_system_items_b msi
 WHERE   1 = 1
 and oeh.org_id = 378
 and mr.organization_id = msi.organization_id
 and mr.inventory_item_id = msi.inventory_item_id
 and mr.demand_source_line_id =  oel.line_id
 and rt.rowid = rt_dfv.rowid
 and oel.payment_term_id = rt.term_id
 and oeh.org_id = oel.org_id
 and oel.header_id = oeh.header_id
 and oeh.flow_status_code = 'BOOKED'
 and oos.order_source_id = oeh.order_source_id
 and oos.name = 'Portal'
```

If i delete this statement:  `and oeh.flow_status_code = 'BOOKED`' it does not show the error message but i need to have that condition

Have you got any idea? Why is this happening?

EDIT: i have edited my query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's only one division being performed in this operation and the divisor is `oel.ordered_quantity`, so it appears that at least one row in `oe_order_lines_all` has an `ordered_quantity` of zero.

You can change the line which reads

```
(oel.tax_value/oel.ordered_quantity) unit_tax_value,
```

to

```
(oel.tax_value/NULLIF(oel.ordered_quantity, 0)) unit_tax_value,
```

Alternatively, you can add

```
and oel.ordered_quantity <> 0
```

to the end of the `WHERE` clause.

Either way, it won't give you the divide-by-zero error any more, but there may be other issues which I can't predict.

Comment: Thank you for replying, i am cheking this out.

Comment: Why after deleting this statement it worked just fine: and oeh.flow_status_code = 'BOOKED'?

Comment: Apparently the `oe_order_lines_all` row with `ORDERED_QUANTITY` equal to zero is related to an `oe_order_headers_all` row with `FLOW_STATUS_CODE` equal to 'BOOKED'.

Comment: Yeah, i think so, you're right. Dude, do you know the Oracle 11g model?

Comment: I mean, does this make any sense to you:  (oel.tax_value/oel.ordered_quantity) unit_tax_value?

Comment: I don't know anything about the data you're working with. As far as "Does dividing tax by ordered quantity to produce a tax-per-ordered-unit" make sense, all I can say is that mathematically it seems to work. Whether or not it "makes sense" in the context of the program you're writing is not something I can offer any advice on.